# How to fix 'TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' when running pyautogui.locateOnScreen()?

Tags: python, pyautogui

im writing a program that would be able to detect the shiny sprite of whatever pokemon that im hunting, however, whenever i run pyautogui.locateOnScreen() i raise a TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

```
import pyautogui as pag
pag.locateOnScreen('beldum.png')
```

i also took the screenshot of the image myself, but i heard that using pyautogui's own screenshot function is better. i tried doing this, but i get the same type error whenever i try to do it.

Here are the tracebacks that I got.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/file", line 3, in <module>
    pag.locateOnScreen('beldum.png')
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 172, in wrapper
    return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 210, in locateOnScreen
    return pyscreeze.locateOnScreen(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 375, in locateOnScreen
    screenshotIm = screenshot(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 527, in _screenshot_osx
    if tuple(PIL__version__) < (6, 2, 1):

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: What is the version of Pillow?

Comment: Try to upgrade pillow. pip install --upgrade pillow

Comment: That traceback is missing the actual error...

Comment: Pillow is 9.5.0. I tried upgrading pillow, but it still ends up with the type error. The actual error is in the title, the TypeError: '<' ... ,but I added it to the traceback.

Comment: Can you make sure `PIL__version__` comes from the right package? Where is it defined? Do you have a local file which shadows the package (like calling your own script `pillow.py` or some such)?

Comment: The line *if tuple(PIL__version__) < (6, 2, 1):* doesn't exist in \_\_init__.py in the latest version of PyScreeze (0.1.28)

Answer (score 24):

I had the same problem when using pyautogui. I'm using Python 3.8, and the version of pyautogui is 9.5.0. Actually, this is a bug in the Python framework packages. I don't know if Python 3.11 works the same way. Anyway, this is how I met this problem and fixed it.

I have this error report:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py", line 528, in _screenshot_osx
    if tuple(PIL__version__) < (6, 2, 1):
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Then I clicked into this report file and and trace back the value of `PIL__version__`. It's defined like this: `__version__ = "9.5.0"`

Now we find the problem. A simple test program can tell you everything:

```
__version__ = "9.5.0"
print(tuple(__version__))
print(type(tuple(__version__)))
print((6, 2, 1))
print(type((6,2,1)))
```

The output you'll get looks like this:

```
('9', '.', '5', '.', '0')
<class 'tuple'>
(6, 2, 1)
<class 'tuple'>
```

They are both tuples, but the elements inside this tuple are `str` and `int` types. Of course they can't be compared.

So you need to click into the reported error file. Replace this code:

```
if tuple(PIL__version__) < (6, 2, 1):
```

with this code:

```
if tuple(map(int, PIL__version__.split("."))) < (6, 2, 1):
```

Now everything should work fine.

Comment: this should be made into a PR

Comment: absolute legend!

Comment: "Actually, this is a bug in the Python framework packages." - no, it's a bug *between* Pillow, which decided to change how it stores the version information, and PyAutoGUI, which didn't change to match. There is no such thing as "the Python framework packages"; that "Python.framework" folder name is just an implementation detail of how **Python itself** is installed **specifically on Mac**.

Answer (score 11):

You can also patch it on startup :

```py
import pyscreeze
import PIL

__PIL_TUPLE_VERSION = tuple(int(x) for x in PIL.__version__.split("."))
pyscreeze.PIL__version__ = __PIL_TUPLE_VERSION

<rest of your app>
```

**Disclaimer** this won't work on some edge cases. and can also break due to code changes on `pyscreeze`

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this following**

1.Open a **`__init__.py`** in your path `"/path/to/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyscreeze/__init__.py"`.
On the Spyder or the other.

2.You just replace this code in line 527

```
if tuple(PIL__version__) < (6, 2, 1):
```

with

```
if tuple([int(x) for x in PIL__version__.split(".")])< (6, 2, 1):
```

3.Save the file.

I have the same problem and these step work for me. Hope it's useful.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).